# Comparing complexities

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, little-o

I have these three questions for an exam review:

1. If `f(n) = 2n - 3` give two different functions `g(n)` and `h(n)` (so `g(n)` doesn't equal `h(n)`) such that `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `f(n) = O(h(n))`
2. Now do the same again with functions `g'(n)` and `h'(n)`, but this time the function should be of the form
   `g'(n) = Ɵ(f(n))` and `f(n) = o(h'(n))`
3. Is it possible for a function `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`?

I know that a function is `O(n)` of another, if it is less than or equal to the other function. So I think 1. could be `g(n) = 2n²-3` and `h(n) = 2n²-10`.

I also know that a function is `Ɵ(n)` of another if it is basically equal to the other function (we can ignore constants), and `o(n)` if it is only less than the function, so for 2. I think you could have `g'(n) = 2n-15` and `h'(n) = 2n`.

To 3.: It is possible for a function to be both `O(n)` and `Ω(n)` because `O(n)` and `Ω(n)` allows for the function to be the same as the given function, so you could have a function `g(n)` that equals `f(n)` and satisfies the rules for being both `O` and `Ω`.

Can someone please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  It would probably be on topic at Computer Science.SE or Math.SE.

Comment: But all these topics can be used when studying running times of programs.

Comment: Ask a question about studying the running time of an actual program, and I'll reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are mostly right. But I would like to add some points:

Given is `f(n) = 2n - 3`

1. With `g(n) = 2n²-3` and `h(n) = 2n²-10` `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` and in `O(h(n))`. But your g(n) and h(n) are basicly the same, at least they are both in `Θ(n²)`. There exists many other function that would also work. E.g.

   - `f(n) ∈ O(n)     ⇒     g(n) = n`
   - `f(n) ∈ O(nk)    ⇒     g(n) = nk   ∀ k ≥ 1`
   - `f(n) ∈ O(2ⁿ)    ⇒     g(n) = 2ⁿ`
2. `g'(n) = 2n-15` reduces to `g'(n) = n`, if we think in complexities, and this is right. In fact, it is the only possible answer.
   But `f(n) ∈ o(h'(n))` does not hold for `h'(n) = 2n`. Little-o means that

   ```
   limn → ∞ | f(n)/g(n) | = 0           ⇔           f(n) ∈ o(g(n))
   ```

   So you can choose `h'(n) = n²` or more general `h'(n) = nk  ∀ k > 1` or `h'(n) = cⁿ` for a constant `c > 1`.
3. Yes it is possible and you can take it also as a definition for `Θ(g(n))`:

   ```
   f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))        ⇔      f(n) ∈ O(g(n))    and    f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))
   ```